# Getting a list of differences between list of installed packages and list of desired packages in ansible

Tags: ansible

**(See update2 below for my final word on this.)**

I'd like to have ansible generate a list of missing packages by comparing the installed packages with a list of desired packages.  (The list of missing packages would then be passed to yum for installation.)  It seems like this can be done using some combination of package_facts and the "difference" filter, but I can't come up with the right syntax.

For example, the following gives information about installed packages:

```
 - name: get the rpm package facts
   package_facts:

 - name: show them
   debug: var=ansible_facts.packages
```

and lists can be compared like this:

```
- name: Find difference of two lists
  gather_facts: no
  hosts: localhost
  vars:
      missing: "{{ input1|difference(input2) }}"
      input1:
      - john
      - mary
      input2:
      - john
      - alice
  tasks:
    - name: 'Print them out'
      debug: var=missing
```

How can I plug these two techniques together to make a list that's usable later by yum?

**Update**

Zigarn's answer below gets me very close to what I want (with the caveat that it's "set_fact:" instead of "set_facts:" and "package:" instead of "packages:").  Here's what I'm trying now:

```
 - name: Retrieve the installed packages
  package_facts:

- name: Get only list of name of installed packages
  set_fact:
     installed_packages: "{{ ansible_facts.packages.keys() }}"

- name: Specify list of desired packages
  set_fact:
    desired_packages:
      - emacs
      - antiword
      - gimp
      - junk
      - otherstuff
- name: Compute missing packages
  set_fact:
    missing_packages: "{{ desired_packages | difference (installed_packages) }}"

- name: Print list of missing packages
  debug: var=missing_packages

- name: Print list of installed packages
  debug: var=installed_packages

- name: Install missing packages
  ignore_errors: yes
  yum:
    skip_broken: yes
    name: "{{ item }}"
    state: present
  loop: "{{ missing_packages }}"
```

This does indeed try to install missing packages, with the odd exception of "emacs" which isn't currently installed, but also isn't put into the missing_packages list by ansible.  This might just be something odd about this particular package, so I'm going to go ahead and mark zigarn's post as the answer but continue to look into the problem.

Regarding why I'm doing it this way, two reasons:  First, I'm using a loop and a list instead of passing all the packages to yum at once because I want to avoid the case where a typo in the list of desired packages, or a named package that's not in the repositories, makes yum fail to install any of the listed packages.  "skip_broken" doesn't help in these cases.  Second, I'm installing a lot of packages (thousands) and yum is very slow, so whittling down the list to just the missing packages can save an hour on the time it takes to update a computer.

**Update2**

After experimenting with this for a while, I've decided that I'm not confident that I understand the data structure returned by ansible_facts.packages and the way "difference" interprets it, so the following is what I'm going to stick with for now.

```
- name: Get list of installed packages without arch
  command: "rpm -q --qf '%{NAME}\n' -a"
  args:
      warn: false
  register: installed_packages_noarch

- name: Get list of installed packages with arch
  command: "rpm -q --qf '%{NAME}.%{ARCH}\n' -a"
  args:
      warn: false
  register: installed_packages_arch

- name: Combine the lists of packages with and without arch
  set_fact:
    installed_packages: "{{ installed_packages_noarch.stdout_lines + installed_packages_arch.stdout_lines }}"

- name: Install missing packages
  ignore_errors: yes
  yum:
    skip_broken: yes
    state: present
    name: "{{ item }}"
  loop: "{{ desired_packages | difference (installed_packages) }}"
  vars:
    desired_packages:
      - emacs
      - gimp
      - somethingelse
      - anotherthing
```

Note that I've fallen back to just using rpm to get the list of installed packages, and that I actually have it generate two lists and combine them: A list of bare package names, and a list of packagename.architecture.  This lets me specify things like libsomething.i686 or libother.x86_64 in the list of desired packages in cases where I want packages of multiple architectures installed.

Comment: Can you add the output of the list of the installed packages? (to try to understand why emacs is skipped)
Looping over a lot of package may be even slower than giving a long list as it means an SSH roundtrip for every package to install.

Comment: There are thousands of installed packages, so I won't list them all, but the ones that contain the string "emacs" are: 'xemacs-packages-extra'
 'xemacs-common'
 'xemacs'
 'emacs-filesystem'
 'xemacs-filesystem'
 'xemacs-packages-base'
Regarding round-trip time, that's not an issue because these are all being run locally, not over ssh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to know that you don't need to compute yourself the list of missing packages as the `package` module (or platform-specific module `yum`, `apt`, ...) is idempotent and will anyway check itself the missing packages to install them.

But, if you need it for another purpose, here is how to do it.

`package_facts` is populating the `ansible_facts.packages` variables with a specific structured documented in https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/package_facts_module.html#returned-facts

If you want to compare it with a simple list of package names, you need to only use the keys of the package_facts. Then you can get the difference between the two lists:

```yaml
- name: Retrieve the installed packages
  package_facts:
- name: Get only list of name of installed packages
  set_fact:
     installed_packages: "{{ ansible_facts.packages.keys() }}"
- name: Compute missing packages
  set_fact:
    missing_packages: "{{ package_list_you_want | difference (installed_packages) }}"
- name: Install missing packages
  package:
    name: "{{ missing_packages }}"
    state: present
```

Comment: Thanks. This seems to (at least almost) get me where I need to go.  See my update on the original post.